# Identifying the currently running script

Tags: python, argparse

Say I have a `config.py` that manages the command-line arguments

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('common_argument')
args = parser.parse_args()
input_common = args. common_argument
```

This file is imported from many other script which I execute in my project. However, among those are scripts that expect additional arguments, e.g. `special_file.py`. How can I add these arguments?

**Alternative 1**

In `config.py`, I identify the script that is importing it to add the additional argument. Say there was a variable like `__importing_file__`, then I could do

```
if __importing_file__ == 'special_file':
    parser.add_argument('special_argument')
```

However, I couldn't find out how to identify the currently running script. Is it possible?

**Alternative 2**

In my `special_file.py` I can simply add another argument and parse again, i.e.

```
from config import *

parser.add_argument('special_argument')
args = parser.parse_args()
input_special = args.special_argument
```

However, python does not recognize the `special_argument`.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `__file__`. This is however **NOT** to be mistaken with `sys.argv[0]`.

`sys.argv[0]` gives the module's entrypoint i.e where the application was started from. **IF** this was a **django** app `sys.argv[0]` would have given `manage.py` while `__file__` would have returned the **absolute** path of the currently running script.

Comment: I can't confirm this. If I add `print(__file__)` to the module that is imported, it shows the path to the module that is being imported.